# How to obtain ActiveNode records from neo4j-core query results?

Tags: ruby, neo4j

If I use the `neo4j-core` way to query a neo4j instance it will return records of the `Neo4j::Core::Node` class:

```
cypher = 'MATCH (n) RETURN n LIMIT 10'
results = neo4j_session.query(cypher)
results.first[:n] # => Neo4j::Core::Node
```

How can I convert these to the ActiveNode type of records that was used to populate the database?